# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (it mustn`t be so!)

Tags: javascript, php

I have function in my code that is presented below. So, while working I see a beautiful error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

There is my code:

```
 .on('slider', function (data) {
        if(ngtimerStatus) {
            ngtimerStatus = false;
            $('.forceClose').addClass('msgs-not-visible');
            console.log(data);
            var users = data.users;
            console.log(users);
            users = mulAndShuffle(users, Math.ceil(110 / users.length));
            users[6] = data.winner;
            users[100] = data.winner;
            html = '';
...
```

All in all I found that $data is nit empty!
It includes

```
{
  "chance": 98.6,
  "users": [
    {
      "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:25:59",
      "created_at": "2015-11-24 14:56:20",
      "remember_token": "xespxJgYoYR9Pe1WQOYjMa3xuN4JYG708XJ20qhMJbMNfA2B1a5yMM8p5jnm",
      "is_moderator": "0",
      "is_admin": "0",
      "votes": "0",
      "id": "1",
      "username": "dota2expert.ru",
      "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/a8/a80a9f13fdbfcf02053b73f55a4a0e8596221137_full.jpg",
      "steamid": "STEAM_0:1:-24976791",
      "steamid64": "76561198031473286",
      "trade_link": "https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=71207558&token=LbivBnv-",
      "accessToken": "LbivBnv-",
      "money": "0.00"
    },
    {
      "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
      "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27",
      "remember_token": "ZPcNSqC3nGsiuLdWTKp3IzVuqhwmj1RUYADTIOIxCGLqjfSa6V8U14qTIhs4",
      "is_moderator": "0",
      "is_admin": "0",
      "votes": "0",
      "id": "7",
      "username": "SKONIKS",
      "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
      "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
      "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
      "trade_link": "",
      "accessToken": "",
      "money": "275.00"
    }
  ],
  "tickets": "478986",
  "ticket": 173512,
  "round_number": "0.362248050305609551",
  "winner": {
    "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:42:37",
    "id": "7",
    "username": "SKONIKS",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
    "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
    "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
    "money": 4370,
    "votes": "0",
    "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27"
  },
  "game": {
    "winner": {
      "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:42:37",
      "id": "7",
      "username": "SKONIKS",
      "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
      "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
      "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
      "money": 4370,
      "votes": "0",
      "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27"
    },
    "bets": [
      {
        "user": {
          "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:25:59",
          "id": "1",
          "username": "dota2expert.ru",
          "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/a8/a80a9f13fdbfcf02053b73f55a4a0e8596221137_full.jpg",
          "steamid": "STEAM_0:1:-24976791",
          "steamid64": "76561198031473286",
          "money": "0.00",
          "votes": "0",
          "created_at": "2015-11-24 14:56:20"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-11-24 21:43:38",
        "created_at": "2015-11-24 21:43:38",
        "id": "5",
        "user_id": "1",
        "game_id": "2",
        "items": "[{\"name\":\"Inscribed Crescent Bow\",\"market_hash_name\":\"Inscribed Crescent Bow\",\"classid\":\"503011467\",\"rarity\":\"mythical\",\"price\":\"62.85\"}]",
        "itemsCount": "1",
        "price": "62.85",
        "from": "0",
        "to": "6284"
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:25:59",
          "id": "1",
          "username": "dota2expert.ru",
          "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/a8/a80a9f13fdbfcf02053b73f55a4a0e8596221137_full.jpg",
          "steamid": "STEAM_0:1:-24976791",
          "steamid64": "76561198031473286",
          "money": "0.00",
          "votes": "0",
          "created_at": "2015-11-24 14:56:20"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-11-24 21:50:23",
        "created_at": "2015-11-24 21:50:23",
        "id": "6",
        "user_id": "1",
        "game_id": "2",
        "items": "[{\"name\":\"Talon of the Scarlet Raven\",\"market_hash_name\":\"Talon of the Scarlet Raven\",\"classid\":\"217224920\",\"rarity\":\"uncommon\",\"price\":\"2.02\"}]",
        "itemsCount": "1",
        "price": "2.02",
        "from": "6285",
        "to": "6486"
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
          "id": "7",
          "username": "SKONIKS",
          "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
          "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
          "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
          "money": "275.00",
          "votes": "0",
          "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:18",
        "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:18",
        "id": "7",
        "user_id": "7",
        "game_id": "2",
        "items": "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 315 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_1.png\",\"price\":\"315.00\"}]",
        "itemsCount": "1",
        "price": "315.00",
        "from": "6487",
        "to": "37986"
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
          "id": "7",
          "username": "SKONIKS",
          "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
          "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
          "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
          "money": "275.00",
          "votes": "0",
          "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:19",
        "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:19",
        "id": "8",
        "user_id": "7",
        "game_id": "2",
        "items": "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 315 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_1.png\",\"price\":\"315.00\"}]",
        "itemsCount": "1",
        "price": "315.00",
        "from": "37987",
        "to": "69486"
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
          "id": "7",
          "username": "SKONIKS",
          "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
          "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
          "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
          "money": "275.00",
          "votes": "0",
          "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:21",
        "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:21",
        "id": "9",
        "user_id": "7",
        "game_id": "2",
        "items": "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 315 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_1.png\",\"price\":\"315.00\"}]",
        "itemsCount": "1",
        "price": "315.00",
        "from": "69487",
        "to": "100986"
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
          "id": "7",
          "username": "SKONIKS",
          "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
          "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
          "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
          "money": "275.00",
          "votes": "0",
          "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:25",
        "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:25",
        "id": "10",
        "user_id": "7",
        "game_id": "2",
        "items": "[{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 3150 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_4.png\",\"price\":\"3150.00\"}]",
        "itemsCount": "1",
        "price": "3150.00",
        "from": "100987",
        "to": "415986"
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
          "id": "7",
          "username": "SKONIKS",
          "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
          "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
          "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
          "money": "275.00",
          "votes": "0",
          "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:26",
        "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:26",
        "id": "11",
        "user_id": "7",
        "game_id": "2",
        "items": "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 315 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_1.png\",\"price\":\"315.00\"}]",
        "itemsCount": "1",
        "price": "315.00",
        "from": "415987",
        "to": "447486"
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
          "id": "7",
          "username": "SKONIKS",
          "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d4174b5213f60fc9612229320d633d421b373080_full.jpg",
          "steamid": "STEAM_0:0:-4181615",
          "steamid64": "76561198073063637",
          "money": "275.00",
          "votes": "0",
          "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:26:27"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
        "created_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
        "id": "12",
        "user_id": "7",
        "game_id": "2",
        "items": "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 315 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_1.png\",\"price\":\"315.00\"}]",
        "itemsCount": "1",
        "price": "315.00",
        "from": "447487",
        "to": "478986"
      }
    ],
    "updated_at": "2015-11-24 22:42:37",
    "created_at": "2015-11-24 21:18:41",
    "rand_number": "0.362248050305609551",
    "status_prize": "0",
    "id": "2",
    "winner_id": "7",
    "status": 3,
    "items": "8",
    "price": "4789.87",
    "started_at": "2015-11-24 22:28:27",
    "finished_at": {
      "timezone": "Europe/Moscow",
      "timezone_type": 3,
      "date": "2015-11-24 22:42:37"
    },
    "won_items": "\n    [{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 315 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_1.png\",\"price\":\"315.00\"},\n    {\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 3150 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_4.png\",\"price\":\"3150.00\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 315 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_1.png\",\"price\":\"315.00\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"\\u041a\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\\u043e\\u0447\\u043a\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430 315 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\",\"img\":\"assets\\/img\\/tickets\\/card_1.png\",\"price\":\"315.00\"}]"
  }
}
```

where you can simply found part named "users" but data.users is empty! (underfined). Can you help me with it?

Comment: What do you see in the console for `console.log(users);` ?

Comment: json is now more readable (I've used jq to quickly format it) but in my opinion it is too long to be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use `data = JSON.parse(data);`, before accessing `data.users`? It's hard to tell from your example.